# What are the different methods to import a table with CLOB column into Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, clob

[Description of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrJj7.png)

This is my table.

And I have an excel file with two columns. The second column has a huge string.
Tried to import this table using SQLDeveloper 4.2.
Tried all formats like xlxs, csv, txt. But I get an error the following error message:
DATA IS NOT COMPATIBLE WITH COLUMN DEFINITION OR IS NOT AVAILABLE FOR A NOT NULLABLE COLUMN.
[error message on the CLOB column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCRzz.png)

Also tried setting both the columns as null and not null.

Please, help me resolve this issue.
I really appreciate if anyone can share me the various methods which can be applied in order to import huge files like this one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

well i see 3 ways to do it

1. Create external teable on your file. https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/external-tables-containing-lob-data
2. load whole file with data pump into intermediate table and processed it into oracle with dbms_lob.
3. devide a big column to several little colmns or several rows, upload it and again processed it into Oracle